# Trimming announcements in sharepoint

Tags: html, sharepoint

In sharepoint, when you post a long annoucement the webpart trims it to the first two lines but preserves any links in the html.

I'm trying to create a custom webpart that trims long text and want to reuse this functionality. Does anyone know where in the sharepoint libraries it lies?

Answer (score 3):

What makes announcements appear trimmed is this specific line in the `<ListViewXml />` tag inside the webpart code on the page:

```
<Limit Len="250" MoreText="..." AutoHyperLink="TRUE" AutoNewLine="TRUE"><Column Name="Body"/></Limit>
```

These properties map to the [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms451066(v=office.12).aspx) class, and you might be looking for the `AutoHyperLink` property.